# Update angular directive attribute value from parent controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I have a Angular directive like this:

```
angular.module("app", ["customers"]).run();

angular.module("app").controller("appController", function($scope) {
  $scope.customers = [{ name: "Microsoft" }];

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("timeout");
    $scope.customers = [{ name: "Apple" }];
  }, 1500);
});

angular.module("customers", []).directive("customerList", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template:
      '<ul><li ng-repeat="customer in vm.customers">{{customer.name}}</li></ul>',
    scope: {
      customers: "=customers"
    },
    bindToController: true,
    controller: customerListController,
    controllerAs: "vm"
  };
});

angular
  .module("customers")
  .controller("customerListController", customerListController);

customerListController.$inject = ["$scope"];

function customerListController($scope) {
  const vm = this;
  $scope.$watch('vm.customers', function(newValue) {
    console.log(newValue)
  })
}
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController">
  <customer-list customers="customers"></customer-list>
</div>
```

[Here's a pen of it](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JMeoqe)

What I want to achieve is to update the customer list in the `appController` and have it updated inside the directive as well so my list shows `Apple` after 1500ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `setTimeout` Angular won't know about changes you made to the `$scope.customers`. Use `$timeout` service which will trigger scope digest automatically after timeout:

```
.controller("appController", function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.customers = [{ name: "Microsoft" }];

  $timeout(function() {
    console.log("timeout");
    $scope.customers = [{ name: "Apple" }];
  }, 1500);
});
```

With `setTimeout` you need to trigger digest manually with `$scope.$apply()` after you assign new value to `$scope.customers`.

**Demo:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzaVRb?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. I used the `SetTimeout` function to show my intention. However in my application I need to update the list in the controller using a Button click (outside the directive) which does not work.

Comment: I just tried it in the Pen using a button and it works as expected. Looks like the issue is in my code elsewhere.